# Name for this algorithm to roughly shuffle infinite list with finite memory

Tags: algorithms, terminology, randomness

A couple of friends and I were talking about the best way to attempt to shuffle a infinite list, given finite memory.
We immediately concluded that you could not do so, at least not in the same sense that you could shuffle a finite list.
But we devised an approximation.

**Initialize**: Draw from the infinite list $L$, a array of items $W$ which we will call the window, of size $w$ items ($w\in\mathbb{Z}$)

**Output**
To output an element from our shuffled list:

1. $i\leftarrow rand(0:w)$  -- Generate a random integer $i$, with $0\le i < w$
2. $r\leftarrow W[i]$ -- select the item to return
3. $W[i]\leftarrow head(L)$ -- replace it with the first item in the infinite list
4. $L\leftarrow tail(L)$ -- remove that item that we took
5. Output $r$

So the basic idea is that we give a random item from a finite window, which we take with replacement from the infinite list.

Now I am sure this is not a new idea.
So I am looking for a name for it, so I can look into it and read up on its properties. Eg it is clear that by increasing $w$ increases the "entropy" in some sense. But I am not sure if for a fixed $w$ if over time it converges to a steady state for the expected positional distance between adjacent output items.

Also so that if I end up implementing and using it in my current work, I can cite the right paper.

Comment: Looks related to [Reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).